# How do you format Date fields in an R data.frame?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I am trying to create a data.frame that contains 'datetime' and 'numeric' fields and insert data into it.
Being new to R, and having a 'novice' level of skill, I'm not sure how to format it...

Here's the code I'm trying to work. 
Note the 'commented out' sections are variations.
I am getting all kinds of strange output for the 'Time' field.

```
#df.02 <- data.frame(Time = as.Date(character())
#df.02 <- data.frame(Time = as.Date(numeric())
#df.02 <- data.frame(Time = as.POSIXct(strptime(character())
df.02 <- data.frame(Time = as.POSIXct(strptime(character())
#df.02 <- data.frame(Time = as.Date(character())
                , Open = numeric()
                , High = numeric() 
                , Low = numeric()  
                , Close = numeric()  
                , Volume = numeric()
                , stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

time <- as.Date("01.02.2014 00:00:00.000")
#time <- as.Date("01.02.2014 00:00:00.000", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
#time <- strptime("01.02.2014 00:00:00.000", "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%OS")
#time <- as.POSIXct("01.02.2014 00:00:00.000", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")

open <- 1111.111
high <- 2222.222
low <- 3333.333
close <- 4444.444
volume <- 0.0000

df.02 <- cbind(Time = time, Open = open, High = high, Low = low, Close = close, Volume = volume)
df.02
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend checkout out the lubridate packgage, it's sort of the one-stop shop for all things datetime-related.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with jarfa. lubridate is a GREAT package for this. For example, you could do this:

```
 library(lubridate)
 time <- mdy_hms("01.02.2014 00:00:00.000")
```

and now, if you check the class of "time", it is "POSIXct" "POSIXt".

Comment: Which data.frame declaration version do I use? I'm getting a numeric result for the Time field...                               Time     Open     High      Low
[1,] 1388620800 1111.111 2222.222 3333.333
        Close Volume
[1,] 4444.444      0

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "declaration", but here's one way to do it:

     Data <- data.frame(time = "01.02.2014 00:00:00.000", 
                   open = 1111.111,
                   high = 2222.222,
                   low = 3333.333,
                   close = 4444.444,
                   volume = 0.0000)
     Data$time <- mdy_hms(Data$time)